# Bash script to copy the directory structure from source directory into target directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am very new to Bash scritping and to get some practice, I am attempting to write a script that takes in a source directory and a destination directory. The script will search the source directory and copy its structure of sub-directories into the target directory (any files will be ignored, just the directories themselves will be duplicated). The source directory can have any number of sub-directories at any depth. What would be the best way to achieve this? I have started by attempting to write a recursive function where, if a directory is found, the function is called recursively onto this directory. However, due to my lack of experience with scripting, I have been stumped.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]; then 
    echo "ERROR: Script needs 2 arguments: $0 source/directory/ target/directory/"
    exit
fi

SOURCE_DIR=$1
TARGET_DIR=$2

function searchForDirectory {
    for FILE in ls $SOURCE_DIR/*; do #should be 'ls *current_directory*'
        if [ -d $FILE ]; then
            searchForDirectory #call function recursively onto $FILE
            #Do stuff here to create copy of this directory in target dir
        fi
    done
}

if [ ! -d $SOURCE_DIR ]; then 
    echo "ERROR: Source directory does not exist"
    exit
else
    searchForDirectory
fi
```

I know that this is just a skeleton function, and a lot more work would need to be put into it, but I'm just looking for guidance as to whether this is the correct way to go about this before I go any further, and if so, what would be my next step? How do I pass a directory into my function?

**EDIT: Here is my solution thanks to Ivan's help below**
    #! /bin/bash

```
if [ ! $# -eq 2 ]; then 
    echo -e "\nERROR: Script needs 2 arguments:\n$0 source/directory/ target/directory/\n"
    exit
fi

function recursiveDuplication {
    for file in `ls $1`; do
        if [ -d $1/$file ] && [ ! -d $2/$file ]; then
            mkdir $2/$file
            recursiveDuplication $1/$file $2/$file
        elif [[ $1/$file == *.png ]]; then
            convert $1/$file $2/$file
        fi
    done
}

if [ ! -d $1 ]; then 
    echo -e "\nERROR: $1 does not exist\n"
    exit
elif [ -d $2 ] && [ ! -w $2 ]; then
    echo -e "\nERROR: You do not have permission to write to $2\n"
    exit
elif [ ! -d $2 ]; then
    echo -e "\nSUCCESS: $2 has been created"
    mkdir $2
fi

recursiveDuplication $1 $2
```

There are two issues with this solution:

1. As Rany Albeg Wein explained below, using 'ls' is not a good solution - and I have seen why when there is a space in a directory/*.png name.
2. I am also attempting to copy any *.png file from the source to the target and convert it to a *.jpg image in the target. How can I do this? I am attempting to use ImageMagick's `convert image.png image.jpg` command, but do not know how to do so when the `image.png` is being referred to as `$file`?

Comment: If you are interested, it can be accomplished by `find` and `cpio`. `find source -type d | cpio -pd target`. The whole tree from `source` will be copied to `target`. If the command is executed by `root`, permission and ownership can be preserved. If executed by non-`root`, only permission can be preserved.

Comment: @KOB A new answer had been added with a tested safe solution, using `gnu cpio`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1st argument - source dir, 2nd - destination

function rrr {
  for i in `ls $1`
  do
    if [ -d $1/$i ]
    then
      mkdir $2/$i
      rrr $1/$i $2/$i
    fi
  done
}


rrr $1  $2
```

Comment: Meh, that is the same, as in question

Comment: Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: 
                `for file in *.txt`. Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: idem what about special chars in names, permissions and symbolic links?

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein See my edit where I have explained the problem that I have come across when using `ls`, as you explained. How can I use the same for loop without using `ls`?

Comment: @KOB Please see the link in my previous comment. You'll learn the correct way to approach your problem.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein I have read through the link, but I am still struggling with applying the same syntax of the for loop to my own problem. In the link, he uses `for file in *`, which iterates over the files in the current directory, whereas I am trying to iterate over the files in`$1`. I initially thought this would be done using `for file in $1/*`, but that is not the case.

Comment: @KOB Sorry, but I did not read your original question, but if `$1` is a directory, indeed `for file in "$1"/*; do ...;done` will do ( notice that `$1` is double quoted! - `"$1"` ).

Comment: @KOB - when you use `for i in "$i/*"`, the value of `$i` will contain the directory `$1`. There is no need to use `$1/$i`.

Comment: ... "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and **every** expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes,  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words .

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein I now have an issue, I think, with the `if` condition - `for file in "$1"/*; do
    if [ -d $1/$file ] && [ ! -d $2/$file ]; then
      mkdir $2/$file;
        recursiveDuplication $1/$file $2/$file`. I believe that now because `file` contains the entire filepath, `$1/$file` is basically 2 of the same filepaths combined. I tried replacing this with just `$file`, but that did not work.

Comment: @KOB Please take a look at this answer: [Copy only folders not files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365877/copy-only-folders-not-files)

Comment: @Ivan This solution does not work to copy directory tree, see the test in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify a lot

```
$ find a -type d | xargs -I d mkdir -p copy/d
```

copy the tree structure from directory `a` to new directory under `copy`

```
$ tree a
a
|-- b
|   |-- c
|   |   `-- file4
|   |-- d
|   |   `-- file4
|   `-- file3
`-- file2

3 directories, 4 files


$ tree copy
copy
`-- a
    `-- b
        |-- c
        `-- d

4 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Although the OP didn't specify whether to preserve permission and ownership, you should mention that none of those will be preserved with this method.

Comment: In addition directory names containing special chars (`´` `"` `*` ` ` `\n`) will break this no? what about symbolic links ?

Comment: moreover `mkdir` Is going to attempt to create directories that have already been created due to `-p`, generating errors, right?

Comment: @karakfa This solution does not work to copy directory tree, see the test in my answer. This error is generated: `xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option `

Answer (score 0):

This solution has been tested with directory names containing special chars, a loop in the directory tree and a broken symbolic link.

There is bellow a stansard solution:

```
( cd source/ ; find . -depth -type d -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 -I xxx mkdir -p ../destination/xxx )
```

And there is a second solution using `gnu cpio`:

```
( cd source/ ; find . -depth -type d -printf "%p\0" | cpio --null -pd ../destination )
```

The test:

```
$ mkdir -p source/a/ba/c/d/e
$ mkdir -p source/a/bb/c/d/e
$ mkdir -p source/a/b/ca/d/e
$ ln -s source/broken/link source/a/ba/c/d/e/broken
$ (cd source/a/ba && ln -s ../../a  tree-loop)
$ mkdir -p source/z/"$(printf "\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11\12\13\14\15\16\17\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\35\36\37\40\41\42\43\44\45\46\47\72\73\74\75\76\77\100\133\134\135\1336\137\140\173\174\175\176\177dir")" 
$ touch source/a/b/"$(printf "\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11\12\13\14\15\16\17\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\35\36\37\40\41\42\43\44\45\46\47\72\73\74\75\76\77\100\133\134\135\1336\137\140\173\174\175\176\177file")"
$ ls 
source
$ find source -depth
source/z/??????????????????????????????? !"#$%&':;<=>?@[\][6_`{|}~?dir
source/z
source/a/ba/tree-loop
source/a/ba/c/d/e/broken
source/a/ba/c/d/e
source/a/ba/c/d
source/a/ba/c
source/a/ba
source/a/b/ca/d/e
source/a/b/ca/d
source/a/b/ca
source/a/b/??????????????????????????????? !"#$%&':;<=>?@[\][6_`{|}~?file
source/a/b
source/a/bb/c/d/e
source/a/bb/c/d
source/a/bb/c
source/a/bb
source/a
source

$ ( cd source/ ; find . -depth -type d -printf "%p\0" | xargs -0 -I xxx mkdir -p ../destination/xxx )
$ find destination/ -depth 
destination/z/??????????????????????????????? !"#$%&':;<=>?@[\][6_`{|}~?dir
destination/z
destination/a/ba/c/d/e
destination/a/ba/c/d
destination/a/ba/c
destination/a/ba
destination/a/b/ca/d/e
destination/a/b/ca/d
destination/a/b/ca
destination/a/b
destination/a/bb/c/d/e
destination/a/bb/c/d
destination/a/bb/c
destination/a/bb
destination/a
destination/
```

The `gnu cpio` test:

```
$ rm -rf destination
$ ( cd source/ ; find . -depth -type d -printf "%p\0" | cpio --null -pd ../destination )
0 blocks

$ find destination -depth
destination/z/??????????????????????????????? !"#$%&':;<=>?@[\][6_`{|}~?dir
destination/z
destination/a/ba/c/d/e
destination/a/ba/c/d
destination/a/ba/c
destination/a/ba
destination/a/b/ca/d/e
destination/a/b/ca/d
destination/a/b/ca
destination/a/b
destination/a/bb/c/d/e
destination/a/bb/c/d
destination/a/bb/c
destination/a/bb
destination/a
destination
```